# Why 'would be' is used in this line

Tags: modal-verbs, modality, will-would

In India,there is a great cricket player named Sachin(he has retired few years back).One of his colleagues (who used to  play at international level along with him)praised him and said following line:

"I always found it difficult to pick you in the nets(practice area) **Sachin** **sir**,whether it **would be**  leg-spin,off-spin,cutter, wrong-un(these four are some terms of the game)."

Why is **would be** used here?Why not 'is' or 'was'?

Comment: It seems an infelicitous use of "would". We might more naturally say "whether it was/be (as) leg spin ..."

Comment: "is" would not be a good choice here because it talks about the past; "was" is the better choice. "be" would be a great choice if he were talking about possibilities in the present or future: "I **will** find it difficult to pick you in the nets,Sachin, sir, whether it *be* legspin, cutter, wrong-un." The reason for this is that "whether it be" means "if it be this or if it not be this/(if it be that)."

Answer (score 1):

I believe his colleague used "would be" here because he was trying to speak in the imperfect tense.  Unlike many Romance languages, which have a bustling imperfect inflectional scheme, English does not.  Instead, English uses semi-modal constructions like "used to", as well as the simple past tense, to form an imperfect meaning.  One of the most widely used simple past tense verbs in English that form the imperfect tense is "would", which is the past tense of "will".  In definition no. 8 on freedictionary.com, "would" is defined as follows:

> 8. Used to express repeated or habitual action in the past: *Every morning we would walk in the garden.*

Other examples besides the one given in definition no. 8 are as follows:

> When I was younger, I **would go** for walks on the boardwalk.
>
> My dog **would** always **wait** by the door for me to come home.  He
>   **would do** it without failure until the day he died.

Despite this use of "would, the simple past tense, along with the semi-modal "used to", is often employed to do this job:

> When I was younger, I **used to go** for walks on the boardwalk.
>
> When I was younger, I **went** for walks *all the time* on the
>   boardwalk.
>
> My dog (always) **used to wait** by the door for me to come home.  He
>   **used to do** it without failure until the day he died.
>
> My dog *always* **waited** by the door for me to come home.  He
>   **did** it *over and over* without failure until the day he died.

In my opinion, "was" would have been a better choice here:

> "I always found it difficult to pick you in the nets (practice area),
>   Sachin, sir, whether it **was** leg-spin, off-spin, cutter, wrong-un (these
>   four are some terms of the game)."

Despite my thinking that "was" is a better choice, I do believe that "would be" is an acceptable alternative to convey the imperfect meaning of this statement.  In my mind, it's all about style in this instance.  As Bill J states above, it seems that it may be somewhat of an infelicitous use of "would" herein.  I think it might have sounded better had he said it this way:

> "...whether it **was** leg-spin, off-spin, cutter, wrong-un ***that we
>   would be doing***."

I hope this might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck.